# How often ping the server when using XMPP on a mobile device (e.g. Android)?

Tags: android, xmpp, ping, battery

I'm developing IM application which uses XMPP protocol. My question I think is quite easy:

How often I should ping the server?

What is a good pattern to ping the server, to prevent losing connection and not doing this too often, to do not kill the battery?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You have to make a tradeoff between battery life and dead connection detection/connection timeout avoidance. There will probably be no default value that fits every user. For example some mobile carrier (i.e. I've got reports from france ones) seem to have a ridiculous low TCP timeouts of < 2 minutes, which means your ping interval would have to been lower as 2 minutes. But activating your mobile radio every 2 minutes is fatal with regard to battery life.

I recommend having the client check every 30 minutes *if there has been no Stanza/Nonza received within the 30 minutes* and, if not, sending a ping. Smack's [`ServerPingWithAlarmManager`](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ping/android/ServerPingWithAlarmManager.html) does exactly that on Android.

On Server side, you should do similar, but ideally using a bit longer time span, e.g. 35 or 40 minutes, in order to let the client ping "win" most of the time.

I assume that this is the best trade-off. But this value is just a best guess that has not been calculated by extensive experiments and the evaluation of such. You may want to make it a user setting and/or provide some sort of more or less heuristic to determine the best value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Pidgin](https://hg.pidgin.im/pidgin/main/file/9438f4b2904d/libpurple/connection.c) pings about half a minute. That should be a good enough time interval. Although I would go for maybe 45 seconds to a minute.

Comment: That is way to often for a mobile device.

Comment: Do you want to drain the users battery totally?? damn